# LaTeX with markdown and tables

Tags: tables, macros, markdown

I'm trying to build up a new documentation system using Markdown and LaTeX. After several hours most things are running smooth, but tables are a bit complicated.

Most of the text can be written with Markdown syntax, included by

```
\usepackage[fencedCode,inlineFootnotes,citations,definitionLists,hashEnumerators,smartEllipses,hybrid]{markdown}
```

But tables with defined cell-widths and multicolumns have to be done in LaTeX native code.

To make the document more easy to write down, I am planning to create a LaTeX macro creating these tables. So the writer only has to fill some macro variables and LaTeX is buliding the table.

Even this is almost working BUT

I have to stop the Markdown environment with `\end{markdown}` just before creating the table and entable Markdown with `\begin{markdown}`. This isn't working well within the document like:

```
\end{markdown}

\marcocreatetable
    {parameter 1}
    {parameter 2}

\begin{markdown}
```

But, when trying to put these commands to the macro like

```
\newcommand{\marcocreatetable}[2]{

\end{markdown}
\begin{longtable}{>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm} p{2.5cm} p{3.5cm} p{2.5cm}}
         \arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
        Cell1&\multicolumn{2}{l}{S\{1\} #1}&\multicolumn{2}{r}{#2}\\\hline
        Cell x&cell y &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{cell w}}&cell z&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{6}}\\
\end{longtable}
\begin{markdown}
}
```

an using the macro like

```
%\end{markdown}

\marcocreatetable
    {parameter 1}
    {parameter 2}

%\begin{markdown}
```

LaTeX complains about

> ```
> \begin{document} ended by \end{markdown}.
> ```

Seems ending `markdown` within the makro is not working very well.
And yes, ending `markdown` at the beginning of a macro and starting `markdown` at the ending of a macro maybe bad code, but I'd like to create a table with just a single command.

Any suggestions to a big LaTeX noop?

Comment: you have not provided any usable example so it is hard to answer but if the `markdown` environment changes catcodes then it is like `verbatim` and can not be used in the argument of any command.

Comment: Since the release of [version 2.8.0](https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/releases/tag/2.8.0), the Markdown package supports tables.

Answer (score 1):

I did find a solution.

Within the macro, I have to use `\endmarkdown{}` instead of `\end{markdown}`.